# How to correctly use strace -e read=fd option?

Tags: file-descriptors, strace

I'm trying to monitor read activity on a particular file descriptor in a running process. Here is the C++ test bench I'm testing various solutions on:

```cpp
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int fd1=open("/tmp/testfile", O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
    const int fd2=open("/tmp/testfile", O_RDONLY);
    write(fd1, "Hello, world!", 13);
    std::cout << "PID: " << getpid() << ", fds: " << fd1 << "," << fd2 << "\n";
    for(;;)
    {
        char b;
        if(!read(fd1,&b, 1))
            lseek(fd1,0,SEEK_SET);
    }
}
```

Its typical output is:

```
PID: 14992, fds: 3,4
```

So, I'm trying to use strace to trace the reads of the file descriptor 3:

```
strace -p 14992 -e trace=none -e read=3
```

What I'm getting is just the message `strace: Process 14992 attached`, and nothing more. If I instead trace all the `read` system calls, I do get a lot of output:

```
$ strace -p 14992 -e trace=read
strace: Process 14992 attached
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
read(3, "H", 1)                         = 1
read(3, "e", 1)                         = 1
read(3, "l", 1)                         = 1
read(3, "l", 1)                         = 1
read(3, "o", 1)                         = 1
read(3, ",", 1)                         = 1
read(3, " ", 1)                         = 1
<...>
```

But strace manual says about `-e read=set`:

> Note  that  this  is independent  from  the  normal  tracing of the `read` system call which is controlled by the option -e trace=read.

So I suppose that my `trace=none`, which is supposed to avoid tracing anything unrelated to my `read=3` option is correct.

Apparently, I'm doing something wrong. So, how should I actually use strace to trace only the `read` system call, and only when `fd==3`? Note that filtering output using `grep` is not an option, since it'd slow down a real-world application I'm going to trace.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure how to interpret the sentence you quote from the manpage, but disabling all tracing disables all `read` tracing too: I/O tracing happens after a syscall is traced, and *that* only happens for enabled syscalls.

```
strace -e trace=none -e read=3
```

means “disable all syscall traces, and whenever a syscall is traced which reads from file descriptor 3, dump its I/O”.

```
strace -e read -e read=3
```

shows both calls to `read` and all the information read from file descriptor 3, but it doesn’t filter the general `read` syscall traces at all, only the I/O dumps.

Put another way, `read=3` doesn’t filter all trace options; it requests that reads from file descriptor 3 have their I/O dumped.

Looking through the `strace` source code, there doesn’t appear to be a way to do what you’re after.

Comment: Well, if I now set `-e read=4` instead of `-e read=3`, I'll still get the reads of 3, so this latter option is then useless. The goal I'm trying to achieve is filtering at an earlier stage than `grep` would.

Comment: Yes, I don’t think it’s possible to do what you’re after, within `strace`.