# strace write calls to stdout

Tags: strace

Is there a way to use strace to just show a process's stdout? I know I can do

`strace -p pid -e write`

but that shows calls to write(2) to multiple file descriptors. When reading the man page I also saw the `-e write=` option but I'm getting a bunch of other stuff when using

`strace -p pid -e write=1`

Basically, I want the output of the first command (`strace -p pid -e write`) but only  showing the `write(1,...` outputs. I know I could filter the output, but I'm wondering if there's a way for strace to do this directly.

Comment: No that's not possible afaik. You'll have to pass the output to grep. See also [this Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562214/308316). It would be great if a more tcpdump-like tool for monitoring system calls existed, but I don't know anything of the sort.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the PID you can hook the `-P` parameter to the STDOUT file descriptor in /proc. Just like this:

```
strace -p PID -P /proc/PID/fd/1 -e write
```

You can find all open file descriptors of a process in /proc/PID/fd. 1 is a symlink to the STDOUT file.

Comment: Quick tip: use `-s <number>` to increase the output size. By default, strace will only print 32 chars from the captured line

Answer (score 2):

You can filter `strace` output using the `-P` parameter, when you know the file descriptor path.

As per [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace):

> -y          Print paths associated with file descriptor arguments.
>
> -P path     Trace only system calls accessing path.  Multiple -P options can be used to specify several paths.

It is not necessary to use `-y` when you use `-P`. You can use `-y` to initially find out the path of your file descriptor. This could be something like `/dev/pts/0`.

Here is an example that can be used to display output from a process that was disconnected from bash using the `disown` command:

```
strace -e trace=write -s 1000 -p12345 -P "/dev/pts/0 (deleted)" 2>&1 | awk -F "\"" '{print $2}'
```

In this example, `12345` is the PID of the process that was started in a `bash` session and initially wrote to `stdout`. We disconnected the process from `bash` using `disown 12345` and closed bash. Using the above command, we can display output from this process in a different bash session.

Answer (score 1):

No.  But perhaps rather than using `strace` you can simply monitor the pid's stdout using `tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1` to nevertheless achieve your goal.

Example:

```
$ for F in $(seq 1 100);do echo $F;sleep 1;done >/tmp/foo 2>&1 &
[1] 163
$ tail -f /proc/163/fd/1
4
5
6
7
8
9
^C
$
```

Comment: I can run your example, but I'm having trouble getting this to work for the actual process I care about. Seems to open fine but no output, even though strace shows the right output. I'm the owning user so permissions shouldn't be the problem. I inspected the file and it's telling me its an invalid symlink. Any thoughts on what might be wrong here?

Comment: This assumes that the standard output is a regular file, which is not a restriction given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool, [catp](https://github.com/rapiz1/catp/), to do this task. So you can `catp $PID`.

Basically, it's the same as `strace`, utilizing `ptrace` under the hood. Instead of printing various tracing information, it prints the tracee's output to stdout.